# SQL LISTADO EMPLEADOS

Tags: mysql, sql

Obtener utilizando una consulta SQL el listado de departamentos que tienen 2 o mas empleados. Indicar el nombre del departamento (campo nom_depart) y la cantidad de empleados, ordenado por el nombre del departamento de forma ascendente.

Tablas:

- APPX_employee (id,department_id)
- APPX_department (id, nom_depart)

Tengo esto pero pues como se muestra en la imagen no es lo que se solicita:

```
select dept.nom_depart,
       cant.department_id 
from APPX_department as dept  
inner join APPX_employee as cant where (dept.id=1 
AND cant.department_id=2) OR (dept.id=2 AND cant.department_id=2) 
group by dept.nom_depart
```

LA SALIDA ESPERADA ES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes probar de esta forma, tambien tienes que revisar bien tu consulta esta un poco mal estructurada,  select dept.nom_depart,
       cant.department_id 
from APPX_department as dept, PPX_employee as empleado where empleado.departament_id=dept.id having count(*)>=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select d.nomDpto, count(e.idDpto) as TotalEmp
from departamentos d
inner join empleados e
on d.id = e.idDpto
group by d.nomDpto 
having count(e.idDpto) >= 2
order by d.nomDpto
```

Se usa la **clausula inner join** para relacionar las dos tablas por un campo en común, posteriormente se emplea la **cláusula group by** para agrupar los registros por el **campo nomDpto** de la **tabla departamentos** y entonces vendría la **cláusula having** que se usa para filtrar los agrupamientos que se hacen con la **clausula group by**, después vendría el ordenamiento por el campo deseado y por último vendría la proyección de los campos a través de la **cláusula select** mostrando el nombre del departamento y usando la **función de agregación count** para contar todos los **campos idDpto** de la **tabla empleados** que tienen el mismo **idDpto**.

**Nota:** Yo pongo nombres genéricos a los campos y tablas quizá tus nombres sean diferentes a los que uso.

Comment: Muchas gracias así era

Comment: @BryanBeltran, que bueno que resolviste, podrías por favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te comento:

Dado el contexto de la pregunta, la consulta podría quedar de esta forma:

```
SELECT APPX_department.nom_depart, COUNT(APPX_employee.department_id) AS Total
FROM APPX_department 
INNER JOIN APPX_employee ON APPX_department.id = APPX_employee.department_id
GROUP BY APPX_department.nom_depart
HAVING Total >= 2;
```

Te comento que:

- No debes colocar en el `SELECT` la columna de la llave foránea, dado que según lo que expones ese valor no es el esperado, si no un conteo de las veces que esta aparece como referencia de un empleado asignado a un X departamento, lo que si puedes hacer es usar una función de agregación tal como `COUNT` y pasarle la FK
- Posterior dado que necesitas el conteo de empleados por departamento deberás agrupar, de otro modo todo se reducirá a una sola fila.

Comment: Ya el resto (**ordenamiento**) te lo dejo a ti